# Cookie Request Header for Web Fonts

Tags: css, cookies, font-face, webfonts

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to load authenticated HTML content from a different domain via CORS. This content includes references to images, styles, and fonts.

I can load the html, images, styles, etc. but for some reason my cookie headers are not being passed along to any web fonts, resulting in a 403 forbidden error.

If after logging in, I try to access the webfont directly, I'm able to do so and it downloads fine, but it's failing inside of the @font-face at-rule in our CSS.

How can I get the browser to send along the auth cookie when it requests the web fonts?  Is this possible? Is something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this issue is also written about here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411338

Any work arounds?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We just ran into it too :(

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old, but I had the same problem only in Chrome for Android.

Not tested yet but guess IOS browsers may also show this problem.

I solved adding the css which includes the font-face with jquery after authentication has been completed.

Something like:

```
$.when(my-function).done(function() {

$('head').append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'css/main.css'));
$('head').append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'css/font-awesome.min.css'));
});
```