# Cookies not being sent via font-face request

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have a cookie set on the domain `example.com`.
This cookie is included in requests for fonts when I have this in my CSS and going to the web server

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Uniform;
    src: url("/font1.otf")
    format("opentype");
}
```

However if I try and load up a font from a different server hosted on a subdomain then the cookie does not get send though

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Uniform;
    src: url("https://asset.example.com/font1.otf")
    format("opentype");
}
```

However if I load up a image as a background image on a div the cookie is sent though absolutely fine. For example

```css
.bug {
  background-image: url("https://asset.example.com/my-img.png");
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  filter: invert(100%);
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

I have been going round in circles for hours on this. Any help would be much apricated

I have tried setting the samesite to all three options on the cookie and if the cookie is secure or not.

Comment: @JoSSte cookies set for a _domain_, are automatically valid for subdomains. And that is the situation here. That the subdomain might resolve to the IP address of a different machine, is not relevant.

Comment: I didn't catch that the root of the subdomain was the same.

Answer (score 1):

Web fonts are treated differently from other types of resources, when it comes to cross-origin requests.

A quick search lead me to [Cookie Request Header for Web Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30248647/1427878), and a comment there is referring to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411338 - and in there you find one comment saying,

> CSS Fonts Module Level 3 says that user agents must use "Anonymous" mode of CORS-enabled fetch [1], that means credentials are not sent regardless of server's Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
> (XMLHttpRequest change of Chrome 37 is unrelated to font fetches.)
>
> [1] http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-fetching-requirements

So what you want here simply *must not* work, due to the specification.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, annoying that web fonts don't work like that. It doesn't quite seem right to me that cookies are send on the same domain but not for cross domain. In my situation I wanted to load them from our API which is on a subdomain. But at least web fonts can be loaded via base64 so there is a workaround.